# jqGrid filter dates only working for equals, not greater than

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filtering

I've been trying to figure out how to get my date column in jqGrid to filter using "less than or equals" or "greater than or equals" ("le" and "ge" respectively) but it only works with "eq" also doesn't work with "lt" or "gt"

Please see this [jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jg2DT/54/](http://jsfiddle.net/Jg2DT/54/) for the code example.

```
colModel: [
        { name: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int", searchoptions:{clearSearch: false}},
        { name: 'name', width: 70, searchoptions:{clearSearch: false}},
        { name: 'surname', width: 100, searchoptions:{clearSearch: false}},
        { name: 'startdate', sorttype: "date", width: 90, 
            searchoptions: {
                searchOperators: true,
                sopt: ['gt', 'eq', 'ge'],
                clearSearch: false,
                dataInit: function(elem) {
                    $(elem).datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
                        autoSize: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        changeMonth: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        showWeek: true
                    });
                }
            },
            formatoptions: {
                srcformat:'mm/dd/Y',
                newformat:'mm/dd/Y'
            }
        }
]
```

Note that if you do an equals it works fine but nothing else works.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can fix the problem by adding `formatter: "date"` property to the definition of the `startdate` column.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply to this. It didn't work at first and other things became priority. Once I did as you suggested I had to change srcformat:'mm/dd/Y', newformat:'mm/dd/Y' to srcformat:'m/d/Y', newformat:'m/d/Y' before it made sense. Also, it still didn't look like it was working until after picking the date I had to click the > or >=, etc. in the filter toolbar to get the new datepicker value to be evaluated.

Comment: @JosephWhite: Sorry, but I'm not sure: is the problem is solved now? [The demo](http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/Jg2DT/68/) seems to me works without any problems with `formatter: "date"`.

Comment: yes, the problem is solved now. I was just explaining that I had used the wrong srcformat is why id did not appear to be working correctly at first. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @JosephWhite: To be exact the `formatoptions` with `srcformat` **was ignored before** because it's the options of the formatter `"date"`. It has no sense to include any options of formatter if you didn't use the formatter at all.